# Multiple return sets from stored procedure .NET Core & Entity Framework

Tags: sql-server, rest, stored-procedures, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I want to load 3 different models from a SQL Server stored procedure which returns 3 different tables, like:

```
 select A.id, A.Name from tableA A

 select B.id, B.Age from tableB B

 select C.Test, C.Param from tableC C
```

Usually, I would handle a single result stored procedure with Entity Framework Core like this:

Context:

```
 public virtual DbQuery<StoredProcedureModel> spModel{ get; set; }

 protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
 {
        modelBuilder.Query<StoredProcedureModel>(entity =>
        {
            entity.Property(e => e.Id)
                    .HasColumnName("Id");
            entity.Property(e => e.Name)
                    .HasColumnName("Name");
        }
 }
```

Repository:

```
return _context.StoredProcedureModel
        .FromSql<StoredProcedureModel>(
            "GET_ID_NAME @ID,@NAME",
            new SqlParameter("@ID", ID),
            new SqlParameter("@NAME", Name))
        .ToList();
```

This is just a dummy example, but I wanted to know if there's a way to load all 3 tables into 3 different models (some of the tables returned have the same column names like "id").

Comment: Not supported (yet).

Comment: See feature request [Support multiple resultsets - GitHub](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/8127).

Answer (score 8):

Currently it is not possible with Entitiy-Framework but there is a [FeatureRequest](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/8127).
As a workaround, according to this [blog post](https://khalidabuhakmeh.com/multiple-result-sets-with-net-core-sql-server) there is a solution with ADO.Net:

First code your classes:

```
public class TableA 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class TableB
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}

public class TableC
{
    public string Test { get; set; }
    public string Param { get; set; }
}

public class StoredProcedureResult
{
    public List<TableA> TableAEntries { get; set; }
    public List<TableB> TableBEntries { get; set; }
    public List<TableC> TableCEntries { get; set; }
}
```

Afterwards code the following function into your CustomDbContext class:

```
public async Task<StoredProcedureResult> GetStoredProcedureResult(int id, string name)
{
    var connection = Database.GetDbConnection();
    await connection.OpenAsync();

    var command = connection.CreateCommand();
    command.CommandText = "GET_ID_NAME @ID, @NAME";
    command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    command.Parameters.Add(new Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@ID", id));
    command.Parameters.Add(new Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@NAME", name));

    var reader = await command.ExecuteReaderAsync();
    var tableAEntries = new List<TableA>();
    var tableBEntries = new List<TableB>();
    var tableCEntries = new List<TableC>();

    while (await reader.ReadAsync())
    {
        tableAEntries.Add(new TableA
        {
            Id = reader.GetInt32("id"),
            Name = reader.GetString("name"),
        });
    }

    await reader.NextResultAsync();

    while (await reader.ReadAsync())
    {
        tableBEntries.Add(new TableB
        {
            Id = reader.GetInt32("id"),
            Age = reader.GetInt32("Age"),
        });
    }

    await reader.NextResultAsync();

    while (await reader.ReadAsync())
    {
        tableCEntries.Add(new TableC
        {
            Test = reader.GetString("Test"),
            Param = reader.GetString("Param"),
        });
    }

    var storedProcedureResult = new StoredProcedureResult();

    storedProcedureResult.TableAEntries = tableAEntries;
    storedProcedureResult.TableBEntries = tableBEntries;
    storedProcedureResult.TableCEntries = tableCEntries;

    await reader.CloseAsync();

    return storedProcedureResult;
}
```

Comment: Strictly, that's not an Entity-Framework solution. It's ADO.Net. The question is whether there's native support [as there is in EF6](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/modeling/designer/advanced/multiple-result-sets).

Comment: Thanks @GertArnold, I will update my answer that it is a solution with ADO.Net and not Entity-Framework